Group structure from unique solvability of linear equations?
Commonly, a group is defined as follows:
Definition. Let $G$ be a set and $\ast:G\times G\to G$ a binary operation on that set. Then the pair $(G,\ast)$ is called a $\textbf{group}$ if the following statements are true:

The operation $\ast$ is associative;
There exists an element $e\in G$ such that $g\ast e=e\ast g=g$ for all $g\in G$;
For all $g\in G$ there exists an element $g^{\prime}\in G$ such that $g\ast g^{\prime}=g^{\prime}\ast g=e$.

Although, we can make this definition slightly weaker in order to obtain an equivalent formulation of what it means for a pair $(G,\ast)$ to be a group, and that can happen as follows:
Theorem.  Let $G$ be a set endowed with a binary operation $\ast:G\times G\to G$. Then the pair $(G,\ast)$ is a group if and only if the following statements are true:

The operation $\ast$ is associative;
There exists an element $e\in G$ such that $g\ast e=g$ for all $g\in G$;
For all $g\in G$ there exists an element $g^{\prime}\in G$ such that $g\ast g^{\prime}=e$.

Now, we state an important corollary of that theorem as can be seen right below:
Corollary. Let $G$ be a non-empty set endowed with a binary operation $\ast:G\times G\to G$ that is also associative. Then the pair $(G,\ast)$ is a group if and only if the equations $a\ast x=b$ and $y\ast a=b$ are solvable for any $a,b\in G$.
The observation I want to make is that, for the converse, existence is enough to imply a group structure, but only because the binary operation was assumed to be associative. Therefore, my question would be: if we did not assume a priori the associative law, but instead we added unique solvability as an additional hypothesis to the converse implication, would it be possible to deduce a group structure? To be more precise, I make the following conjecture:
Conjecture. Let $G$ be a non-empty set endowed with a binary operation $\ast:G\times G\to G$.
Then the pair $(G,\ast)$ is a group if and only if the equations $a\ast x=b$ and $y\ast a=b$ are uniquely solvable for any $a,b\in G$.
The forward direction is true nonetheless, but what about the converse?

The existence of unique solutions to the equations is equivalent to asking that the Cayley table for the operation $*$ be a Latin square. But it is well-known that there are Latin squares that define operations that are not associative, which you can see in the duplicate.

@ArturoMagidin How is unique solvability equivalent to asking that the Cayley table for the operation ∗ be a Latin square? It's not obvious to me.

Being a Latin square means that each element of the set occurs exactly once in each row and each column. Label,the rows and columns with the elements. Solving $ax=b$ means finding the column on row $a$ that contains $b$ (because the entry in row $a$ column $x$ is the result of the product $ax$). Solving $yb=a$ means finding the row in column $b$ that contains $a$.

@ArturoMagidin Thank you, that's the enlightenment I needed. Take care!
